# How can i develop Augmented Reality application by using Android SDK?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I want to develop Augment Reality application by using Android SDK. but i have serched a lot i didn't get any good information. what i have learned after searching, by using thirdparty tools we can develop Augmented Reality apps for Android. is this correct? otherwise Plase correct me.

Thanks,
pavan.

Comment: StackExchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30436/augmented-reality

Answer (score 4):

See the example here in [AndAr](http://code.google.com/p/andar/) project.

Comment: Thank you very much! Vladimar. i will try it and let you know how it works for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source of some ARView apps like [Mixare](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/), Wikitude etc. [Wikitude](http://developer.wikitude.com/) has its own SDK. You have to sign for developer account in Wikitude to download the SDk.